# Preserving the subscript and superscript while reading the content of a cell in "xlsx" Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, format, subscript, superscript

I am trying to develop a tool in python so that the user input strings are stored in an excel "xlsx" file. My script is supposed to read the cell contents of the excel file and plot them using Matplotib (Like the title of the graph, Y label, etc). However, reading the content having subscript or superscript strings (such as scientific notation or units) is failing. I tried different approaches such as Pandas, Win32com, Xlrd but couldn't be successful as they can read plain text only. I am seeking help for it. How can it be achieved? If this can't be done in excel, is there any method to take an input file preserving the format of the string?